# Express the new parameters in terms of the old parameters (SIQR model for mathematical epidemiology)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-modeling

In the model considered here the population is divided into susceptibles (S), infectives (I), isolated or quarantined individuals (Q), and recovered individuals (R), for whom permanent immunity is assumed. Let N denote the total population i.e. $N=S+I+Q+R$, and let $A = S + I + R$ denote the active (nonisolated) individuals. The model takes the form:

$$\begin{align}
\frac{dS}{dt}&=\mu N-\mu S− \sigma S \frac{I}{A}\\
\frac{dI}{dt}&=-(\mu + \gamma)I+\sigma S \frac{I}{A}\\
\frac{dQ}{dt}&=-(\mu+\xi)Q+\gamma I\\
\frac{dR}{dt}&=−\mu R+\xi Q \\
A&=S+I+R
\end{align}$$

￼￼￼￼￼￼All newborns are assumed to be susceptible. $\mu$ is the per capita mortality rate, $\sigma$ is the per capita infection rate of an average susceptible individual provided everybody else is infected, $\gamma$ is the rate at which individuals leave the infective class, and $\xi$ is the rate at which individuals leave the isolated class; all are positive constants.

**Question:** Rescale the model by: $\tau=\sigma t$, $u=S/A$, $y=I/A$, $q=Q/A$, $z=R/A$. Rearrange your new model as follows:

$$\begin{align}
\dot{y}&=y(1-\nu -\theta -y-z+\theta y-(\nu +\zeta)q)\\
\dot{q}&=(1+q)(\theta y-(\nu+\zeta)q) \\
\dot{z}&=\zeta q-\nu z +z(\theta y-(\nu+\zeta)q).
\end{align}$$

Express the new parameters in terms of the old parameters. Check that all the new parameters and variables are dimensionless.

The new parameters are $\nu$, $\theta$, and $\zeta$. The answer should be $\nu=\frac{\mu}{\sigma}$, $\theta=\frac{\gamma}{\sigma}$, and $\zeta=\frac{\xi}{\sigma}$. I am unsure on how to rescale the original model. It has 4 equations, but the new model only has 3 equations. Can someone explain how I should go about rescaling the original model?

Comment: "the new model only has 3 equations" because $u+y+z=1$ hence one can replace $u$ and $\cdot u$ everywhere by $1-y-z$ and $-\dot y-\dot z$ respectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did not understand was that $$\begin{align}
\frac{dI}{dt}&=\frac{dI}{d\tau}\frac{d\tau}{dt}\\
\frac{dI}{dt}&=\dot{I}\sigma
\end{align}$$

Since $I=Ay$ we have $\frac{dI}{dt}=(\dot{A}y+A\dot{y})\sigma=\left(\frac{1}{\sigma}\frac{dA}{dt}+A\dot{y}\right)\sigma=\frac{dA}{dt}+A\dot{y}\sigma$.

Using the fact that A=S+I+R, we have $\frac{dA}{dt}=\mu Q-\gamma I+\xi Q$, so $\frac{dI}{dt}=(\mu Q-\gamma I+\xi Q)y+A\dot{y}\sigma$.

From our original model, $\frac{dI}{dt}=-(\mu+\gamma)I+\sigma S\frac{I}{A}$, so by equating our two equations and then solving for $\dot{y}$ we have

$$-(\mu+\gamma)I+\sigma S\frac{I}{A}=(\mu Q-\gamma I+\xi Q)y+A\dot{y}\sigma$$

$$\dot{y}=\frac{1}{A\sigma}\left(-(\mu+\gamma)I+\sigma S\frac{I}{A}-(\mu Q-\gamma I+\xi Q)y\right)$$

$$=-\left(\frac{\mu}{\sigma}+\frac{\gamma}{\sigma}\right)\frac{I}{A}+\frac{S}{A}\frac{I}{A}-\frac{\mu}{\sigma}\frac{Q}{A}y+\frac{\gamma}{\sigma}\frac{I}{A}y-\frac{\xi}{\sigma}\frac{Q}{A}y$$

Using the proper substitutions, we have
$$\dot{y}=-\left(\frac{\mu}{\sigma}+\frac{\gamma}{\sigma}\right)y+uy-\frac{\mu}{\sigma}qy+\frac{\gamma}{\sigma}y^2-\frac{\xi}{\sigma}qy$$

By factoring, rearranging and using the fact that u=1-y-z, we have
$$\dot{y}=y\left(1-\frac{\mu}{\sigma}-\frac{\gamma}{\sigma}-y-z+\frac{\gamma}{\sigma}y-\left(\frac{\mu}{\sigma}+\frac{\xi}{\sigma}\right)q\right)$$

and can easily see that $\nu=\frac{\mu}{\sigma},\theta=\frac{\gamma}{\sigma}, \zeta=\frac{\xi}{\sigma}$